# d3 - Create new element from the dataset for each node in the selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a bar chart in d3 v5, and am trying to add labels inside each bar (the chart is horizontal).

Currently, each bar is contained in a  `<g>` element. My dataset has multiple elements in it (these are simple objects that have a name and a value), so when I do:

`g.selectAll('text').data(dataset).enter().append('text')`

N `<text>` elements are added to each `<g>`. Instead, I would like  each `<g>` to have a single label that uses a single element in the dataset.

Can this be done using d3? Should I do this somewhere else (when I'm creating the bars of the cart, for instance), and how?

Answer (score 0):

not sure where `g` comes from in your post. With the enter-update-exit, use `selectAll` to bind data to outer most element that represents data item (`<g>`), and then use `select` on the group selection to propagate the bound data item to its (dom) children. Maybe not a best analogy, but if `selectAll` gives you an array, `select` performs a `map` over it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Feel free to change or delete any of the code you see in this editor!
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)

    var data = [{
      c: 'green',
      l: "Green"
    }, {
      c: 'red',
      l: 'Red'
    }];
    
    var g = svg.selectAll("g")
     .data(data);
    
    g.exit().remove();
    
    var newG = g.enter()
     .append('g');
    
    newG.append('rect')
     .attr('width', 100)
     .attr('height', 40)
     .style('fill', 'none');
    
    newG.append('text')
     .attr('y', 30);
    
    // normally I'd reuse the initial `g` variable, but just for clarity
    var newGandUpdatedG = newG.merge(g);
    
    newGandUpdatedG.select('text')
     .text(d => d.l);
    
    newGandUpdatedG.select('rect')
     .style('stroke', d => d.c);
    
    newGandUpdatedG.attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(${i * 120}, 0)`);
     
     
  </script>
</body>
```